firebase dynamic link with flutter not read data in link
i'm using Firebase dynamic link in my app and it work good
it create link, and when share link it opens the app good
my issue is: when open app by link, there is a data like id or page name not appears in dynamic link data
i  will share with you my creation function , example of created link and the data read from dynamic link when open app
creation function:
Future<Uri> createDynamicLink(
  {bool? short, required String pageName, required String id}) async {
final String DynamicLink =
  'https://mydomain.page.link/share?news=$pageName&id=$id';
Uri uri = Uri.parse(DynamicLink);
log("uri $uri");
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
  link: uri,
  uriPrefix: 'https://mydomain.page.link/share',
  androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
  packageName: 'com.somestuff.somestufff',
),
iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
  bundleId: 'com.somestuff.somestufff',
  appStoreId: "647xxxxxx",
),
);
Uri url;
if (short == true) {
   final ShortDynamicLink shortLink =
      await dynamicLinks.buildShortLink(parameters);
    url = Uri.parse(
      "https://mydomain.page.link/${shortLink.shortUrl.path}");
  } else {
     url = await dynamicLinks.buildLink(parameters);
   }
   return url;
 }

the generated link:

the data read from dynamic link:

why page name and id not read in data :(
